# Plot two seperate input files in one graph

Tags: plotting, front-end

So i have the following two text files, [1](http://textuploader.com/d9buf), [2](http://textuploader.com/d9bup)  the first column i each list is the time dimension, 0.00-3.00, and the time moves forward in 0.3 steps. The second column in both files corresponds to the value at each time point. I want to plot them both  in a graph with x-axis going from 0.00-3.00 (Time axis), and y-axis from 70-100 (the second column in both files). Any input how i would do that since im new to mathematica?

Comment: Have you looked at `ListPlot`?  Everything is explained in its documentation.

Comment: is it possible there to create a specific x axis and y axis using listplot?

Comment: Check its PlotRange option.

Comment: f1=Import["file1.txt", "Data"]; f2=Import["file2.txt","Data"]; ListPlot[{f1, f2}] assuming your two files are in a place where MMA looks (or you include a path in the correct notation telling it where to look)